# Get button element by name in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

In my form i am trying to get the button by the name. but it does not return any value

```
<td class="_51m- uiOverlayFooterButtons _51mw">
<button value="1" class="_42ft _42fu layerConfirm autofocus uiOverlayButton selected _42g- _42gy" name="__CONFIRM__" type="submit" tabindex="0">Okay
</button>
<button value="1" class="_42ft _42fu layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _42gy" name="__CANCEL__" id="u_0_0" type="submit">Cancel</button>
</td>
```

and my code is

```
HtmlElement dialogForm = dialogPage.getElementById("form");
 HtmlElement dialogSubmitButton = dialogForm.getElementsByTagName("button").get(1);
```

it returns value when i try to get using name it returns null

```
 HtmlElement dialogSubmitButton = dialogForm.getInputsByName("__CONFIRM__")
```

how would i access an element by name?

Comment: dialogForm. .getInputsByName("__CONFIRM__")  why double . . in this line

Comment: did you check the value of dialogForm??? if its value null means you can't get the value by name

Comment: I checked the dialogForm value. it is working fine for `dialogForm.getElementsByTagName("button").get(1);`

Answer (score 3):

it is not

```
dialogForm.getInputsByName("__CONFIRM__")
```

it is

```
dialogForm.getInputByName("__CONFIRM__")
```

Comment: getElementByName is not available

Comment: try my updated code,you were doing minor mistake,moreover i didn't see you are using htmlunit,i thought its for javascript,sorry for my previous answer

Comment: getInputByName is not a function. I am using htmlunit-core-js-2.12 htmlunit-2.12

Comment: ya thats ok. but i get form as element because i don't have form name and having form id only

Comment: when you tried this **dialogForm.getInputByName("__CONFIRM__")* didn't you get result?

Comment: no. I did not get because in my form there is no name only have id

Comment: Then by id itself you can take name of button,use this may it works for you getHtmlElementById("__CONFIRM__");

Comment: I tried with getFirstByXPath("//button[@name='__CONFIRM__']"). It is working fine